# Visual Studio 2019 UnitTest not running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.8

I created a C# Windows Forms-App (.NET Framework) and now trying to add a UnitTest for it.
For the beginning I tryed the first steps from tutorials in the Internet:

- Add new MSTest-Project
- It automatically creates a first test-class and I added an Assert.IsTrue(true) to it:

```
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    
    namespace MyFirstUnitTest
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I now run the test in Test-Explorer, the test keeps in "not tested" state.
If I take a look in the Output window of Tests I see the Following exception:

```
     ========== Testermittlung wird gestartet ==========
     ========== Testermittlung abgeschlossen: 1 Tests in "2,6 Sek." gefunden ==========
     ========== Testlauf wird gestartet ==========
     Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von Executor "executor://mstestadapter/v2": Could not find file 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Projects\MyFirstUnitTest\TestResults\Deploy_xxxxxxx 2022-08-04 21_06_19'.
     Stapelüberwachung:
        at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, Byte[] securityDescriptor)
        at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Utilities.FileUtility.CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(String directory)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Utilities.DeploymentUtilityBase.CreateDeploymentDirectories(IRunContext runContext)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.TestDeployment.Deploy(IEnumerable`1 tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestExecutionManager.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, TestRunCancellationToken runCancellationToken)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.MSTestExecutor.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.RunTestsWithTests.InvokeExecutor(LazyExtension`2 executor, Tuple`2 executorUri, RunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.RunTestInternalWithExecutors(IEnumerable`1 executorUriExtensionMap, Int64 totalTests)
```

What can I do to get the UnitTest run? The folder its looking for really not exists. Who should create the folder "TestResults" normally?

Side Info:

- I tryed to run Visual Studio with Administrator rights
- I turned of my firewall
- I tryed to create the Test-Project with target Platform .NET core 3.1 and with .NET 5.0
- I restartet Visual Studio multiple times
  Nothing of all these changed anything, I always get the error Message above.

Testproject is using following NuGet Packeges:

- coverlet.collector V3.1.2
- Microsoft.NET-TestSdk V17.2.0
- MSTest.TestAdapter V2.2.10
- MSTest.TestFramework V 2.2.10

Comment: Try putting the project in another folder than the C:\Users\... folder as this folder has a lot of restrictions. Also in case you sync your documents to OneDrive, you do not want to sync all the generated files from bin, obj and TestResults folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
The ransomware-protection of windows prohibited the writing of new files for MSTest.
I set it to allow-list, now it works :)